# Java : How to get the file name?

Tags: java, selenium, file-handling

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://wwww.example.com");

    TakesScreenshot t=(TakesScreenshot)driver;

    File scrFile=t.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);///line 1

    System.out.print(scrFile.exist());
}
}
```

I am trying to take screenshot,So I have written above code.

But the file created at  line 1,should appear in current working directory.

But I am not able to find the file in my current working directory.

And when write `scrFile.exist()` it's returning `true` response which means that the file exists but I am not able to find it.

Can anyone tell me with what name file will be stored?

Comment: check if the file is hidden

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `getScreenshotAs()` method (and any methods that it calls to create the file).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(scrFile.getAbsolutePath());//Line 2
```

Line 2 can be used to get the absolute path of a file created after getscreenshotAs() method execution.

```
System.out.println(scrFile.getName());//Line 3
```

Line 3 can be used to get the file name created after getscreenshotAs() method execution.

Comment: You should take a minute to review the formatting help. You mixed code formatting with bold and also comments which makes it hard to read. In this case, all you needed was code formatting which I have fixed.